# How can user-level software access a captive portal from within OS X?

Tags: macos, captivenetwork

I'm writing a tool to automatically access a WiFi portal and log in. The tools works fine when I'm already connected to the network.

However before I connect to the network, all software on OS X - fails with:

```
ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

Even though my WiFi connection is uo, because I haven't passed the portal yet. To clarify, it's a chicken-and-egg problem:

- I can't access the network because I haven't passed the captive portal
- I can't pass the captive portal because I haven't got on the network yet

**How can user-level software access/route to a captive portal from within OS X?**

[image]